# Dump elementtree into xml file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I created an xml tree with something like this

```
top = Element('top')
child = SubElement(top, 'child')
child.text = 'some text'
```

how do I dump it into an XML file? I tried `top.write(filename)`, but the method doesn't exist.

Comment: Why are you trying to guess the syntax? Have you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to instantiate an [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-objects) object and call [`write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

top = ET.Element('top')
child = ET.SubElement(top, 'child')
child.text = 'some text'

tree = ET.ElementTree(top)
tree.write('output.xml')
```

The contents of the `output.xml` after running the code:

```
<top><child>some text</child></top>
```

Comment: @Bob:  The reason you need an instance of ElementTree is that "This class represents an entire element hierarchy, and adds some extra *support for serialization* to and from standard XML."  (Italics added.)