# How to sort XML by attribute (strings before numbers) in Python

Tags: python, xml, sorting, attributes, alphanumeric

I would like to sort the below xml, by the attribute "value" of the "entry" tags and sort the strings (letters) before the numbers.

```
<test>
    <entry value="-12" />
    <entry value="0" />
    <entry value="043" />
    <entry value="14" />
    <entry value="6" />
    <entry value="_null" />
    <entry value="abc" />
    <entry value="abcd" />
    <entry value="empty" />
    <entry value="false" />
    <entry value="test1" />
    <entry value="test2" />
    <entry value="true" />
</test>
```

I have written some python that sorts this xml, but it sorts first the numbers and then the strings.
I have checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373842/sorting-python-list-to-make-letters-come-before-numbers), but could not implement any of the solutions to sorting XML.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ElT
import os
from os.path import sep

def sort_xml(directory, xml_file, level1_tag, attribute, mode=0):
    #mode 0 - numbers before letters
    #mode 1 - letters before numbers

    file = directory + sep + xml_file

    tree = ElT.parse(file)
    data = tree.getroot()
    els = data.findall(level1_tag)
    
    if mode == 0:
        new_els = sorted(els, key=lambda e: (e.tag, e.attrib[attribute]))
    if mode == 1:
        new_els = sorted(els, key=lambda e: (isinstance(e.tag, (float, int)), e.attrib[attribute]))

    for el in new_els:
        if mode == 0:
            el[:] = sorted(el, key=lambda e: (e.tag, e.attrib[attribute]))
        if mode == 1:
            el[:] = sorted(el, key=lambda e: (isinstance(e.tag, (float, int)), e.attrib[attribute]))
    
    data[:] = new_els

    tree.write(file, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8')

    with open(file, 'r') as fin:
        data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
    with open(file, 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(data[1:])
        
        
sort_xml(os.getcwd(), "test.xml", "entry", "value", 1)
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

Edit1: Desired output

```
<test>
    <entry value="_null" />
    <entry value="abc" />
    <entry value="abcd" />
    <entry value="empty" />
    <entry value="false" />
    <entry value="test1" />
    <entry value="test2" />
    <entry value="true" />
    <entry value="-12" />
    <entry value="0" />
    <entry value="043" />
    <entry value="14" />
    <entry value="6" />
</test>
```

Comment: show the desired output please

Comment: Can you add your expected output order?

Comment: _null is a string - why it goes after the numbers? why -12 is before /this?

Comment: @balderman. The way the xml is sorted right now:

    <entry value="-12" />
    <entry value="/this" />
    <entry value="0" />
    <entry value="043" />
    <entry value="14" />
    <entry value="6" />
    <entry value="_null" />
    <entry value="abc" />
    <entry value="abcd" />
    <entry value="empty" />
    <entry value="false" />
    <entry value="test1" />
    <entry value="test2" />
    <entry value="true" />

I took the part where the letters start and put it at the top. 
This the actual requirement, to have the letters at the top, I don't care about the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you are sorting you are checking if the value is an `int` or `float`. In fact all the values are strings e.g. `isinstance(e.tag, (float, int))` will always be false.

A sorter function like this does what you want

```py
def sorter(x):
    "Check if the value can be interpreted as an integer, then by the string"
    value = x.get("value") 
    def is_integer(i):
        try:
            int(i)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        return True
    return is_integer(value), value
```

which can be used like so (using `StringIO` as a substitute for the file)

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from io import StringIO

xml = """<test>
    <entry value="-12" />
    <entry value="0" />
    <entry value="043" />
    <entry value="14" />
    <entry value="6" />
    <entry value="_null" />
    <entry value="abc" />
    <entry value="abcd" />
    <entry value="empty" />
    <entry value="false" />
    <entry value="test1" />
    <entry value="test2" />
    <entry value="true" />
</test>"""

tree = ElementTree.parse(StringIO(xml))
root = tree.getroot()
root[:] = sorted(root, key=sorter)
tree.write("output.xml")
```

The contents of `output.xml` is

```xml
<test>
    <entry value="_null" />
    <entry value="abc" />
    <entry value="abcd" />
    <entry value="empty" />
    <entry value="false" />
    <entry value="test1" />
    <entry value="test2" />
    <entry value="true" />
    <entry value="-12" />
    <entry value="0" />
    <entry value="043" />
    <entry value="14" />
    <entry value="6" />
</test>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, and keeps all values exactly as they are. Doesn't change 043 to 43.

Answer (score 1):

> I took the part where the letters start and put it at the top. This the actual requirement to have the letters at the top, I don't care about the rest.

below

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<test>
    <entry value="-12" />
    <entry value="/this" />
    <entry value="0" />
    <entry value="043" />
    <entry value="14" />
    <entry value="6" />
    <entry value="_null" />
    <entry value="abc" />
    <entry value="abcd" />
    <entry value="empty" />
    <entry value="false" />
    <entry value="test1" />
    <entry value="test2" />
    <entry value="true" />
</test>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
numeric = []
non_numeric = []
for entry in root.findall('.//entry'):
    try:
        x = int(entry.attrib['value'])
        numeric.append((x, entry.attrib['value']))
    except ValueError as e:
        non_numeric.append(entry.attrib['value'])

sorted(numeric, key=lambda x: x[0])
sorted(non_numeric)

root = ET.Element('test')
for value in non_numeric:
    entry = ET.SubElement(root, 'entry')
    entry.attrib['value'] = value
for value in numeric:
    entry = ET.SubElement(root, 'entry')
    entry.attrib['value'] = str(value[1])
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
   <entry value="/this" />
   <entry value="_null" />
   <entry value="abc" />
   <entry value="abcd" />
   <entry value="empty" />
   <entry value="false" />
   <entry value="test1" />
   <entry value="test2" />
   <entry value="true" />
   <entry value="-12" />
   <entry value="0" />
   <entry value="043" />
   <entry value="14" />
   <entry value="6" />
</test>
```

Comment: This works, but how can I save the output to a file?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25856774/dump-elementtree-into-xml-file

Comment: This solution changes some of the values, for example 043 becomes 43.

Comment: @Mihail-CosminMunteanu fixed. see latest code